# Infinite sequence with repeating elements

Tags: f#

I need to create an infinite sequence containing a subsequence of elements which repeats infinitely.

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 1; 2; 3; 4; 1; 2; 3; 4; ...]
```

So I wrote this:

```
let l = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let s = seq { while true do yield! l }
```

Is there a standard way (function) to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that your approach is good in this scenario. There is no built-in function to implement repetition, but if you need to repeat sequences often, you can define one yourself and make it available in the `Seq` module:

```
module Seq = 
  let repeat items = 
    seq { while true do yield! items }
```

Then you can nicely write `Seq.repeat [ 1 .. 4 ]`, as if `repeat` was a standard F# library function, because F# IntelliSense shows both functions from your `Seq` module and from the `Seq` module as if they were defined in a single module.

Aside from your implementation, you can also use recursive sequence expression, which is another quite common pattern when generating sequences. Using `while` is in some ways imperative  (although you don't need any state for simple repetitions) compared to functional recursion:

```
let rec repeat items = 
  seq { yield! items  
        yield! repeat items }
```

This approach is better when you want to keep some state while generating. For example, generating all numbers `1 ..` using `while` would not be so nice, because you'd need mutable state. Using recursion, you can write the same thing as:

```
let rec numbersFrom n = 
  seq { yield n
        yield! numbersFrom (n + 1) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an idiom for this, and what you have is fine, but here are some alternatives.

If you change your subsequence to an array, you can do

```
let a = [|1; 2; 3; 4|]
let s = Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> a.[i % a.Length])
```

Using what you have, you could also do

```
let l = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let s = Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> l) |> Seq.concat
```

but it's no shorter.

Comment: One gotcha here: `Seq.initInfinite` only generates infinite sequences for certain values of infinity. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370429.aspx): "Iteration can continue up to Int32.MaxValue."

Comment: It fits the Core lib's definition of infinite, which is a usable working definition.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Daniel's answer, but encapsulating it into a function, and pretending that function is in the Seq module:

```
module Seq =
    let infiniteOf repeatedList = 
        Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> repeatedList) 
        |> Seq.concat

// Tests
let intList = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let charList = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd']
let objList = [(new System.Object()); (new System.Object()); (new System.Object()); (new System.Object())]
do
    Seq.infiniteOf intList |> Seq.take 20 |> Seq.iter (fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
    Seq.infiniteOf charList |> Seq.take 20 |> Seq.iter (fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
    Seq.infiniteOf objList |> Seq.take 20 |> Seq.iter (fun item -> printfn "%A" item)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it as a (more-or-less) one-liner, without having to create any helper objects.

```
let s = seq { while true do
                for i in 1 .. 4 -> i }
```

Comment: The [1;2;3;4] list was only an example. In reality I have a list of objects that I need to construct sequence from.